# PagedListPager does not fire related action in controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, pagedlist

PagedListPager does not fire the actual action in controller. Index Post action is never called by pagedlistpager.Here are my methods.

```
    // Get
    public ActionResult Index(string searchItem = "")
    {
        var categories = _categoryService.GetAllCategories(new GetCategoriesInput { Filter = searchItem.ToLower() });
        var model = categories.ToPagedList(1, 10);
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(string searchItem, int? page)
    {
        if (page == null)
        {
            var categories = _categoryService.GetAllCategories(new GetCategoriesInput { Filter = searchItem.ToLower() });
            var model = categories.ToPagedList(1, 10);
            return View(model);
        }
        else
        {
            var categories = _categoryService.GetAllCategories(new GetCategoriesInput { Filter = searchItem.ToLower() });
            var model = categories.ToPagedList((int)page, 10);
            return View(model);
        }

    }
```

And finally my view page.

```
    @using PagedList.Mvc;
    @using PagedList;

    @model IPagedList<Categories.CategoryListDto>

    <div class="text-center">
       @Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("Index", "Category", new { page = page }))
    </div>
```

Can someone point me out what i am missing. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Are you expecting to hit the method marked with `[HttpPost]`? (it wont - it goes to the `[HttpGet]` method, and you need to add the `int? page` parameter and relevant code to that method - the POST method should be deleted)

Comment: yes i expect it to hit that method. why it won't? i leverage from that method for another task.

Comment: Because that not the way `PagedList.MVC` works - its goes to a GET method.

Comment: yes, thank you. it's now working as you described.

Answer (score 0):

```
@using PagedList.Mvc;
@using PagedList;

@model IPagedList<Categories.CategoryListDto>
@Html.Editor("Search", ViewBag.searchItem as string, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "", maxlength = 50 } })
@Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("Index", "Category", new { searchItem = ViewBag.searchItem ,page = page }))
</div>
```